# Relative divs cover fixed div with higher z-index

Tags: html, css

Hi I have the following HTML code

```
<body>
    <div class="relative1"> 
        <div class="fixed1"> </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="relative2"> </div> 
</body>
```

and CSS

```
.relative1 {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1; 
}

.fixed1 {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: green; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 2; 
}

.relative2 {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  left: 30px;
  top: -80px;
  background-color: blue; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1; 
}
```

Example: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DaZzz/WGcRe/)

You can see that `div.relative2` covers my `div.fixed1` what is not what I want. I need to cover everything with my `div.fixed1`. Is there any way to do that without changing css for `.relative1` and `.relative2` css?

Comment: still your question is not clear... pls be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't nest the fixed div within the relative div:

http://jsfiddle.net/WGcRe/1/

```
<body>
    <div class="relative1"> 
    </div>
    <div class="fixed1"> </div>     
    <div class="relative2"> </div> 
</body>
```

Fixed elements are not related to relatively positioned elements; they stick on the screen.
Hence, I don't see a reason to nest them.

Comment: What if I can't do this?

Comment: Because I'm using ember.js and I'm rendering popup div inside of another div. I cannot render it outside because I will miss the data.

Comment: It's related to the first part of [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838707/render-template-in-a-parent-in-ember-js)

Comment: I use Backbone, not Ember, but the logic should be the same. You cannot say 'I have to render this view within that other view'. Rather, you should figure out how to append the div to the dom as a fixed, independent element. It does not make sense to nest an independent piece of html into another div that is technically unrelated. 'I cannot render it outside because I will miss the data.' I'm sorry, but that doesn't make sense to me. Any MVC framework should be able to append a view according to a model to the dom in the way that you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

set

```
.relative2{
z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: I shouldn't change styles for `.relative1` and `.relative1`

Comment: ok so you can use Kim's answear - interference in structure not in css